# Unable to delete an entry-Springs MVC Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to delete an entry through spring mvc but I am unable to do it.I am getting `404` error stating requested resource not found.

My controller code is

```
@RequestMapping("/delete/{user_id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@PathVariable("user_id")Integer user_id){
        userService.removeUser(user_id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userList.html");
    }
```

and that its going to the `UserService` and from there its going to `UserServiceImpl` and from there to `UserDao` to `UserDaoImpl` whose code is

```
public void removeUser(Integer user_id){
        User user = (User) sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                User.class, user_id);
        if (null != user) {
            sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
            System.out.println("Successfully deleted");
        }
```

I did a `hibernate.show_sql=true` int the properties file but still for delete I am getting a `select` statement.

Comment: If you get 404 error it is highly probable that you have problem with request mapping. Try to put Line breakpoint at first line of your "deleteUser" method, run server in debug mode and perform delete request. If debugger stop application execution and you can perform debugging - than problem is somewhere in code. If nothing stops - there is no mapping between your request and "deleteUser" method execution

Comment: Yeah you are right and there is some problem with that.Can you guide me please since I am still a novice.

Comment: How do you perform delete request? via <a href="../delete/4"> or via <form action="../delete.4"> ?

Comment: What is the URL, displayed in the address bar of your browser, of the welcome page of your app? What is the URL, displayed in the address bar of your browser, when you get that 404? My guess is that you forgot to prepend the context path of the application. Show us how you generate the URL.

Comment: I just did some changes in web.xml and changed *.html to /.And now its working but the problem is that data is not getting deleted.

Comment: Hi delete is thorugh dis stmt....<a href="delete/${user.id}">Delete</a>

Comment: Seems like returned user is null. Try to debug do method and check is user null.

Comment: No actually the user is not null since the Syso is getting executed there but in logs the hibernate executes select statement instead of delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap delete code with transaction:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
User user = (User) session.load(User.class, user_id);
if (null != user) {
        session.delete(user);
        System.out.println("Successfully deleted");
}
session.flush();
t.commit()
```

Comment: The problem is its still executing select instead of delete.

Comment: Truely superb...Can you please explain me what went wrong in my earlier code that you changed?

Comment: Entity object may have several states: transient, persist, detached. To delete object it must be in persist (attached to session) state. When transaction is opened after object fetching entity is not in persist state (in detached). So we have to fetch and delete object in scope of one transaction to have object in persist state. For some reasons in your initial code (maybe because of wrong transaction management) user gets detached when execution comes to delete method

Comment: For proper transaction management I can recommend you to use @Transactional spring annotation: http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html